# How do I add a live framecounter to my tkinter window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm doing a project that uses tkinter. The goal is to have some moving object on a screen that react in a certain way to eachother.

Currently I'm trying to add a live frame counter however I don't know how I should update it while it is inside a class.

My current attempt uses the following code to create the display:

```
self.frames = 0
self.framesDisplay = self.create_text(500, 500, text=self.frames)
```

To change it I use:

```
self.frames += 1
self.framesDisplay['text'] = self.frames
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 168, in <module>
    field = World(Map, worldWidth, worldLenght, numberOfAtoms)
  File "file.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.createWorld()
  File "file.py", line 41, in createWorld
    self.run()
  File "file.py", line 92, in run
    self.framesDisplay['text'] = self.frames
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

How should I get this to work? Any thoughts on this would be really appreciated!

This is a simplified version of my full code for context:

```
import tkinter



class World(tkinter.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, width, length):
        self.width = width
        self.length = length

        super().__init__(master, width=self.width, height=self.length, bg="#cccce4")
        self.pack()
        self.frames = 0
        self.framesDisplay = self.create_text(500, 500, text=self.frames)

        self.bard = self.create_oval(10, 10, 30, 30, fill=‘blue’)
            
        
        self.run()


    def run(self):
        self.move(self.bard, 10, 20)


        self.frames += 1
        self.framesDisplaty
        self.after(100, self.run)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    worldWidth = 1000
    worldLenght = 800
    Map = tkinter.Tk()
    Map.geometry(str(worldWidth) + 'x' + str(worldLenght))
    field = World(Map, worldWidth, worldLenght)
    field.mainloop()
    print(field.frames)
```

Comment: Have you tried with [`itemconfigure`](https://tkinter-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widgets/canvas.html?highlight=itemconfig#Canvas.itemconfig)? Should be sth like `self.itemconfig(self.framesDisplay, text=str(self.frames))`

Comment: BTW for further questions, try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is way too much code in your question for the given problem.

Comment: Thank you ,this works!
I clicked the link in your first comment and also saw another tkinter function that I knew nothing about that will be very helpful for this project so thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix the issue, you need to correct the typo and update the text of ***self.framesDisplay*** properly. Here's the corrected version of the run method:

```
    def run(self):
       self.move(self.bard, 10, 20)

       self.frames += 1
       self.itemconfig(self.framesDisplay, text=self.frames)  # Corrected line

       self.after(100, self.run)
```

In the corrected code, I replaced **self.framesDisplaty** with **self.framesDisplay**, and I used the itemconfig method to update the text of self.framesDisplay.